# Cannot find isaacgym after the installation, isaacgym --version isaacgym: command not found

Tags: python, conda, environment, reinforcement-learning, nvidia-isaac

I installed Isaacgym a few days ago and it was working. For other reasons my computer crashed so I had to reinstall everything. I repeated the procedure for installing isaacgym (followed this:download and extract it from https://developer.nvidia.com/isaac-gym/download. “Preview 3” was used for these articles but so far the install seems to work for Preview 4 also

cd isaacgym
./create_conda_env_rlgpu.sh
conda activate rlgpu
update LD_LIBRARY_PATH

modify this to point to the lib dir wherever your rlgpu env was created. check out echo $PATH for hints (when rlgpu is active ofc)

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/miniconda3/envs/rlgpu/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
In rlgpu conda environment I in folder isaacgym/python where there is a setup.py file I executed pip install -e . and installed it correctly (got the message Successfully installed isaacgym-1.0rc4
).
Anyway when I try to see its version it says that the command does not exist, and it cannot execute the files where there is isaacgym imported. But there is no executable on this path /home/miniconda3/envs/rlgpu/bin where as I understod, it should be.
Should I add some other path somewhere?
Could anyone help me please?

I thought that there is a problem in conda so I tried to do the same procedure on my computer, not in conda environment but with the same problem. On my computer I have python 3.8.10 and in conda 3.7.12. Before it was requiring python < 3.9.